# AUAudioUnit hosting

Tags: audiounit, avaudioengine, avaudiounit

Sorry that this question is a bit vague but that's the problem, I've been pretty much shooting in the dark due to being unable to find ANY information on this specific area.
I'm hosting AUAudioUnits on OSX.  That all works fine.  I can find em, load em, instantiate em and use em.  No probs.
But it seems there are more options buried somewhere and I've no idea where to even look to configure this.
So... the problem:  I have a specific AU (Superior Drummer 3 in case it's relevant) that comes in 2 flavours: stereo and 16 channel.  It seems that both come from the same component (I assume via AUAudioUnit.registerSubclass) and it has a configurationDictionary that seems to contain the information for the 16 channel version (configurationDictionary dump here):

configs: ["SupportedChannelLayoutTags": {
Output =     (
6619138,
6684674,
6750210,
6946818
);
}, "HasCustomView": 1, "BusCountWritable": <__NSArrayI 0x600000cd3210>(
0,
0,
0
)
, "ChannelConfigurations": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600000006e00>(
<__NSArrayI 0x600000290620>(
0,
2
)

)
, "InitialOutputs": <__NSArrayI 0x600003025ef0>(
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2
)
]

But I have absolutely no idea where to go from here and am utterly stumped.  How is one supposed to extract that information from the dictionary (given that I have no idea of the type information - and bearing in mind I've no interest in hacking it, I want to know the proper flags etc to do this) and how is one supposed to reconfigure the subclass with that info?
Any help *at all* would be so appreciated I cannot tell you.  Even just a pointer in the right direction.
Cheers